# ASP.NET MVC Use NLog to log for multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nlog

Is it possible to either install nlog and log for multiple projects? Currently I have installed it in my class library with this config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="database"
            connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
            commandText="INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetEventLogs] ([Application], [Logged], [Level],[Message],[UserName],[ServerName],[Port],[Url],[Https],[ServerAddress],[Logger],[Callsite], [Exception]) VALUES (@Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @UserName, @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https, @ServerAddress, @Logger, @CallSite,  @Exception);
            ">

      <parameter name="@application" layout="${appsetting:name=appName}" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@username" layout="${identity}" />
      <parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
      <parameter name="@port" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
      <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
      <parameter name="@https" layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />
      <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

However, currently some of these columns aren't populated properly. Servername is empty, Application Name is empty. I was hoping to use it for multiple projects in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tt should work if the nlog.config is in deployed in the correct folder and the other project has access to the "httpcontext" (e.g. other ASP.NET projects)

Regarding your empty values, check your internal log: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Note that you need [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/) or [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) for `${aspnet-request}`

Comment: I have Nlog.Web installed. I'm running ASP.MVC. Can I install the aspnetcore one? Would it be an issue? Also, what do you mean by httpcontext? Must I pass it through? Currently I have created some controllers to log the entries and reference my class library to use them. Thank you for your help also.